# PHP Multiple uploads keeping files names

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a script that I use to upload multiple images, but this script every time rename my images, and I don't want it. How Can I keep the original image name?
This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
    $target_path = "../images/gallery/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
        // Loop to get individual element from the array
        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));   // Explode file name from dot(.)
        $file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
        $j = $j + 1;      // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 10000000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {     // Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
                // If file moved to uploads folder.
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I hope you can help me, Thanks! :)

Comment: $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image. ??????

Comment: Have I to change that line? How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove this line,

```
$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
```

and just add `$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]`

definitions

**uniqid()** - The uniqid() function generates a unique ID based on the microtime (current time in microseconds).

You can change `max_file_uploads` value on you `php.ini` file. By Default it is `20`. You can increase as much as you want.

Also,You can try this code

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg");
$max_file_size = 10000000; 
$path = "../images/gallery/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but you can explain me better this?

Comment: $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
and just add $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]

Answer (score 0):

```
$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
```

Here you are changing the name of file with `md5(uniqid())` instead of that just replace with file name like `$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but I have this result:
original file name:
image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg, image-3.jpg

result with the changes:
image-1.jpg.jpg, image-1.jpg.jpgimage-2.jpg.jpg, image-1.jpg.jpgimage-2.jpg.jpgimage-3.jpg.jpg

I need to keep just every single file name :)

Comment: Okay i got the issues you need to remove  " $ext[count($ext) - 1]"  this portion of code you will get your desired output.

Comment: So, it should be in this way?
$target_path = $target_path . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code. This should work.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
$target_path = "../images/gallery/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
    // Loop to get individual element from the array
    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $target_path .= $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $j = $j + 1;      // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 10000000) && in_array($ext, $validextensions)) {     // Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
            // If file moved to uploads folder.
            echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
        } else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
        echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I got this error: "Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /web/htdocs/www.xxx.com/xxx/upload/upload.php on line 8
1).***Invalid file Size or Type***

Comment: Change this line: $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);     to: $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: it's ok but I don't want to rename image name, and it renamed the images

Comment: Why using md5 if you want the same name of the images. Why wouldnt you leave them as they are($_FILES['file']['name']);

Comment: Because I found this code online and I don't know how I can change it. Could you help me please? Thanks :)

Comment: md5(uniqueid(rand())); This is for generating some alpha-numeric output. You can use it for passwords.

Comment: Ok you dont have to vote for my answer. :). You can tell us if it worked or not, so somebody else can use it if have same problem.

Comment: Sorry I was busy :) I got again the first error: I got this error: "Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /web/htdocs/www.xxx.com/xxx/upload/upload.php on line 8 1).***Invalid file Size or Type***

Comment: and I will give you my vote if you fix my problem :)